# Add Options in Flyout through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a html snippet as follows

```
     <select id="fiscalFlyout" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout">
        <optgroup label="Fiscal Year">
            <option>2013</option>
            <option>2014</option>
            <option>2015</option>                
        </optgroup>
     </select>
```

Currently, I am adding Years through html. But I want to add them through javascript. So that in future year changes, I do not need to open my code and change it.

Comment: It is not that much of a pain!!!
Hard coding is not a bad option when you consider days,years,months.Because they are fixed.
It will take you about 5 min to reach up to 2200Years and 80+ years to reach that date.So,are you sure you want to add some javascript to it??

Comment: This is what you need!!!
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/curdateform2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

```
Try something like below:

function addOption()
{
var x=document.getElementById("fiscalFlyout");
var option=document.createElement("option");
option.text="your option";
try
  {
  // for IE earlier than version 8
  x.add(option,x.options[null]);
  }
catch (e)
  {
  x.add(option,null);
  }
}
</script>


HTML:

<button type="button" onclick="addOption()">Insert option</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    $('.fiscalFlyout');

    var exists = 0 != $('#fiscalFlyout option[value=' + n + ']').length;
    if (!exists) {
        $('#fiscalFlyout').append($('<option></option>').val(n).html(n));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

suggest to use builtin [WinJS.UI.DatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211681.aspx) control. css classes mentioned in the documentation can be used to style the control. [current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211674.aspx) property can be used [onchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211682.aspx) event to get the selected date.

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout" id="flyout">
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.DatePicker">
    </div>
</div>
```

css below hides the month and date part of the control if you want to display only the year.

```
.win-datepicker-date, .win-datepicker-month
{
    display: none;
}
```